# connection refused when trying to run X client on Mac host from a docker container

Tags: macos, docker, xquartz

I try to run a Linux docker container with some X11 clients.

The host is Mac, with xQuartz installed.

It is started using `-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix`

I see a /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 file in the container.

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 developer developer 0 Mar 28 05:26 X0
```

and in the host

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 username wheel 0 Mar 28 10:56 X0
```

The uid is the same, the gid is different for the above names.

When I start the X11 client, it says it cannot connect to the X server.
The error message:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Eclipse: Cannot open display:
```

The value of the DISPLAY environment variable is :0.

I have tried to disable client authentication in XQuartz, but it did not help.

What could be the cause and the solution of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is

```
export DISPLAY=docker.for.mac.host.internal:0
```

Comment: Before running the container?

Comment: in the container